# Using AppMakr for PhoneGap Application with PLUGINS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, cordova

I am using appmakr to build the Phonegap application. I already have all HTML files, images and Css required for Phonegap.

My question is Can I use PhoneGap Plugins to build apps for AppMakr ?

Does anyone know if AppMakr supports PhoneGap plugins? If so, where would I put the plugin files (.m and .h files)? In the HTML zip I upload to AppMakr (within a "plugins" folder)?

I'm terribly confused.

Looking forward to some quick suggestion and solution to this problem

Thanks in advance.